# Media queries working only partially

Tags: css, media-queries

Basically I'm playing around with these and I noticed that some of the properties do change as I want. Some (text-transform and font-size) have no effect (they work outside of the media query but not in). The *p* and *#icon* part work flawlessly, as well as color and font-family for *.title*, so I have zero clue as to why this happens.

Relevant code snippets:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    p {
        background-color: blue;
    }

    #icon {
        display: none;
    }

    .title {
        color: red;
        text-transform: lowercase;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 10px;
    }

}
```

And for the regular screen size I have

```
.title {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

And in the HTML part

```
<h1 class="title" style="text-align: right; margin-bottom: 0px;">Jane Doette</h1>
```

Comment: create a jsfiddle or something to see.

Comment: Here https://jsfiddle.net/3dbyx4xf/

Comment: your media query should go at the end to avoid being overridden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your media query is placed before the non-media query style. If so, put your media query after: [JS Fiddle - Media Query Last](http://jsfiddle.net/ex73efy7/1/)

```
.title {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    p {
        background-color: blue;
    }
    #icon {
        display: none;
    }
    .title {
        color: red;
        text-transform: lowercase;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 10px;
    }
}
```

Otherwise, if the media query is first, the last styles in the style sheet will take precedent: [JS Fiddle - Media Query First](http://jsfiddle.net/ex73efy7/2/)

Comment: Thanks! This wasn't mentioned in the course I took, so I just thought media queries would override wherever they are.

Answer (score 2):

For rules where the selectors are equally specific, the last one takes precedence.

Make the rule inside the media query more specific, for example changing `.title` to `h1.title`, or place the rules for regular screen size before the media query.